# get element dimensions regardless of rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose we have a 50x100 `div`, if we rotate it 45 degrees, jquery returns different values for width and height. If we rotate it again for 45 degrees, jquery returns 100 for width and 50 for height.

I'm looking for a way to get actual width and height regardless of rotation.

**Note: actually the parent of my element has rotation, and I don't want to get involved with it's rotation. I'm not willing to use sin/cos with jquery width height to get original dimensions.**

Comment: This isn't possible with out figuring out the values yourself. The DOM model only handles rectangles with vertical/horizontal faces. This is why the 45 deg rotation makes the dimensions bigger - it's increased to fit the entire extents of the contents within it.

Comment: Take a piece of paper, put a pen on the desk just outside on each side, rotate the paper by 45deg - see how the paper sticks out over the top of the pens.  This is what is happening - the "pens" need to move to be outside the paper => the width increase to accomodate the rotation.   It's not clear what you mean by "actual width" - do you mean "original width" ?

Comment: Test for `getBoundingClientRect`, `getComputedStyle`, `clientWidth/clientHeight` and `offsetWidth/offsetHeight`: https://jsfiddle.net/bxe1ve9q/

Comment: @yckart thanks, clientWidth/Height works fine.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan seems to be possible according to yckart fiddle.

Comment: @yckart post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @SaeedAdelMehraban Done! :)

Comment: I stand corrected - although I have my doubts if that will work reliably in legacy browsers - IE especially.

Comment: Just use offsetWidth/height just like i wrote in my answer. No need to make it overly complex. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery is an *old* library, it used some different combinations (of `getBoundingClientRect`, `getComputedStyle`, `clientWidth/clientHeight` and `offsetWidth/offsetHeight` (and also `node.style`)) over the times.

So, without knowing your used version of jQuery, it's hard to say what it does internally.

At least `getBoundingClientRect` gives you the actual dimensions of *transformed* elements.

Here's a small test case: https://jsfiddle.net/bxe1ve9q

I would bet that using `clientWidth/clientHeight` or `offsetWidth/offsetHeight` give you the *correct* values.

---

Addendum: As you, probably, no longer use jQuery (which is very good at working around browser bugs), you should keep an eye on those *hiccupillities™*. Here are some resources to look at:

- http://caniuse.com
- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom
- http://www.webbrowsercompatibility.com

Answer (score 1):

A solution to your problem is to use the native `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth`. This since jQuerys `width()` and `height()` functions is finicky at best.

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/4vxnmr4y/2/

The fiddle checks the box both on transitionEnd and each second.
Tested in Chrome, FF, IE11, IE Edge. Try it out!

The gist of it is basically this:

```
var box = $('#box');
var w = box[0].offsetWidth;
var h = box[0].offsetHeight;
```

But in the fiddle i added a lot of code to make it a slighly more realistic real-world sample.